# Java library to convert bmp to jpeg and specify compression

Tags: java, shared-libraries, jpeg, converters, bmp

Looking for a library that allows me to convert bmp to jpeg and specify the compression similar saving in photoshop as a jpeg.
Thank you.

Comment: Not a duplicate - this question asks *which* library to use and how to set the compression.